# Intersection of two homogeneous linear second-order recurrence sequences with constant coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, fibonacci-numbers

Say we are given two sequences $u_n$ and $v_n$, defined by the following homogeneous second-order recurrence relations:
$$u_n=3u_{n-1}-u_{n-2}$$
$$v_n=3av_{n-1}-v_{n-2}$$
where $a$ is a constant and $u_0=u_1=1$. The first recurrence relation implies $u_n$ is a subset of the Fibonacci sequence.

Is there an algorithm for determining the intersection of these two sequences? I know that if $a=1,v_0=2,v_1=5$ then this would be the intersection of subsequences of the Fibonacci and Pell numbers, and this has been shown to be finite. Is there a more general algorithm?

Comment: This is already an open problem if one sequence is an arbitrary linear recurrence and the other is identically zero: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem_problem